# QGIS how obtain multicolour lines from polygon cell grid multicolour

Tags: qgis, color

In QGIS I have different lines with same colour that pass through a grid polygon cell (each cell of the grid have a colour).
When a line cross a cell, it must colour with the relative cell colour. Obviously if the same line pass through more than one cell it must colour with multiple colour.

Example:
cell1=yellow, cell2=red, cell3=green
when the line pass through cell1, cell2 and cell3 than the respective part of the line it will colour by yellow, red and green.

Comment: Does the line have information about the cell it passes thru?

Comment: A line cannot get several colors at a time... I would clip the lines layer with the grid layer in order to get line features that exactly match grid cells. Then, you should be able to color each line feature.